# Resources to learn Java EE with Spring, Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I am from .NET C# background and want to learn Spring and Hibernate. Please point me to relevant sites, tutorials, books etc.

Answer (score 2):

Please oh please don't buy one of those books "Hibernate,Spring,J EE X - quick and painelss", or something like that. It will jumble the frameworks in your head and you won't know how to use them independent of one another.

Look at spring framekwork first, it's the most generic of all, and it has great online documentation:

http://www.springsource.org/documentation

Then for ORM, i would strongly recommend looking up JPA2 as it has alot more nicer features (and less bugs) than hibernate. Download Glassfish 3 Java EE 6 application server from here:
http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1-final.html

, it already comes with Eclipselink JPA2 implementation, and get the book "Mastering JPA2" it's written by one of the JPA2 specs creator and it is great.

Answer (score 2):

I personally point our junior developers to this site http://springbyexample.org/

Answer (score 0):

Manning's [Spring in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182358) was quite useful to me. Apress' [Spring Enterprise Recipes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224975) is also a fine pick. Other than those, I find the online documentation most useful.